# Unidentified component on heating element

Tags: identification, component-failure

Clueless DIYer here, apologies in advance. I'm hoping someone can tell me (approximately, I don't need an exact part) what the circled component it is / what it's for, in order to help me diagnose repeated failures.

Mystery component in context (a dishwasher inline heating element)
[image: Mystery component]

Same part removed from a different element, showing scorching
[image: Same part removed from a different element, showing scorch marks]

Many thanks

Comment: I suggest you make this more clearly a "what is this component" question rather than a "my dishwasher keeps breaking" question; the latter is considered off topic but the former is not.

Comment: It may be a thermostat but more likely an over-temperature safety cutout. It may be inadequately rated for the job.

Comment: it may be only a terminal strip .... the two sections appear to be installed backwards in the metal bracket, so that the tabs are too close together

Comment: @Transistor I've just taken one apart and it's definitely a temperature switch - and since the dishwasher has its own thermostat I'm sure it must be a safety cut-out. If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept - cheers!

Comment: @jsotola your comment led me to the root cause of the problem (see answer and comment), much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a thermostat but more likely an over-temperature safety cutout as the dishwasher probably has a separate variable thermostat for the various programs.

It is odd that that unit has burnt as it should not switch in normal operation - only in a fault. It may be inadequately rated for the job or, more likely, inadequately rated for the temperature of its environment.

Comment: After you helped me identify the component I was able to do some testing and rule them out as the cause of my issue - they're both normally closed and they open under heat just fine. I suspect the problem is actually arcing between the plates, probably because I never replaced the half-melted connector block after the first failure (not shown). The scorching on these components is a red herring.

Comment: Good work. No more washing by hand. More Internet time.